# Matplotlib show() and savefig() inconsistent

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, savefig

Code below should show the same image (green background) both when using .savefig() and .show(), but the savefig image is blank. I know that .show() clears the figures but I call it after .savefig(), so it isn't the case here. Both plt.savefig() and fig.savefig() produce the same blank image.

Code (I'm using Python 3.6.8):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def test(dpi=100):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12.8, 7.2), dpi=dpi)
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('#a8bc95')
    plt.savefig("test.png")
    plt.show()

test()
```

[.show()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTRwE.jpg)

[.savefig()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neSTi.jpg)

Comment: your code works for me (matplotlib version 3.3.0) as expected (saves a green figure)

Comment: Interesting. Do you know which backend your matplotlib uses?

Comment: it uses Qt5 backend

Answer (score 0):

Updating the matplotlib version fixes the problem.